# Angular build optimizer - TypeError: this._createContainer is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, bpmn.io

Compiling an Angular 7.2.5 application with `--prod` produces a strange run-time error.

The stack-trace is

```
ERROR TypeError: this._createContainer is not a function
    at bg.pa (Viewer.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:143)
    at new bg (Modeler.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:129)
    at Qg.ngOnInit (diagram.component.ts:105)
    at core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:28285
    at core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29961
    at Sr (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29900)
    at ao (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:30868)
    at core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:30811
    at Object.updateDirectives (diagram-wrapper.component.html:1)
    at Object.ro [as updateDirectives] (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:30799)
```

However, the `Viewer.js.pre-build-optimizer.js` file  does indeed include the `_createContainer` function

```
export default function Viewer(options) {
  options = assign({}, DEFAULT_OPTIONS, options);
  this._moddle = this._createModdle(options);        // works
  this._container = this._createContainer(options);  // <---

...

Viewer.prototype._createContainer = function(options) {
  var container = domify('<div class="bjs-container"></div>');

  assign(container.style, {
    width: ensureUnit(options.width),
    height: ensureUnit(options.height),
    position: options.position
  });

  return container;
};
```

The library is not a native Angular one, it is https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js
I have no idea where to go with this, and I'd like to maintain the build optimizer.

A couple screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get this to work by overriding the `sideEffects` setting within the problematic modules. Setting `sideEffects: true` will tell webpack that it is unsafe to prune unused exports (See [https://webpack.js.org](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free)).

---

Firstly, create an `extra-webpack.config.js` file in the root of your Angular project, with this content

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            include: [/node_modules\/moddle-xml/],
            sideEffects: true
        }, {
            include: [/node_modules\/diagram-js/],
            sideEffects: true
        }, {
            include: [/node_modules\/bpmn-js/],
            sideEffects: true
        }, {
            include: [/node_modules\/bpmn-moddle/],
            sideEffects: true
        }]
    }
};
```

Or even shorter

```
rules: [
  {
    include: [/node_modules\/(bpmn-js|bpmn-moddle|diagram-js|moddle-xml)/],
    sideEffects: true
  }
]
```

---

Then, update your `angular.json` builder configuration to use the `custom-webpack` builder.

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
"options": {
  "customWebpackConfig": {
    "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
    "mergeStrategies": { "module.rules": "prepend" }
  },
```

This will essentially tell the build optimizer to ignore these modules.

Comment: Superb buddy. Hope you'll get more upvotes for this one.

Comment: I've edited your answer to enhance formatting, and include a simpler reg-exp. It deserves it.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to modify other package.json keys, such as "main"?

Comment: You might be able to do it by creating a rule to use a custom loader - https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader. Alternatively, a bash script to replace the package.json "main" key would work (if ran prebuild).

Comment: I've given a look at Loaders and it might be it. The thing is, should the Loader just add a key to the "source" input object? (which should be the package.json file).

Comment: I think the loader will essentially make the replacements during the bundle (as they are part of webpack), are you trying to replace the "main" for bpmn-js? I noticed recently they have started integrating rollup (https://rollupjs.org) which may resolve the entrypoint issues - https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js/blob/develop/rollup.config.js

Comment: No, to be honest I'm trying to compile with Ivy, and I've got an incompatible dependency, date-fns. NGCC cannot find a valid entry point, and adding a main is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same issue. In my case the solution was in adding **diagram.js** dependency to **package.json**. Like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "diagram-js": "^4.0.0"
    ...
```

**bpmn.js** is written with **diagram.js** library and this function (_createContainer) is inherited from it. 
When developing your application **npm** downloading all dependencies locally to **node_modules** directory. But when you are trying to build **prod** version you should specify all libraries that are used by your application.

Comment: Hi Dmitry! My problem is the Angular Devkit builder, which using Terser removes functions from those libraries, thinking they are not used. I had to disable `buildOptimizer`

Comment: I'm kind of stuck with running the app under prod environment. For now - the only solution is build with flags `--prod --optimization=false`.

Comment: Also, have your seen this article? - https://github.com/narve/angular-bpmn/issues/6, might be helpful

Comment: You can use `optimization=true`, and only `buildOptimizer=false`. You'll get smaller bundles this way.
I have read every page on the internet, even opened an issue on Angular CLI here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14750

Comment: Btw, what I'll do is split my application in "main" + multiple libraries. Libraries will be optimized, while the small "main" one not, because of this. I hope to lower the bundle size